# /etc/fstab - using bash command output to get UUID?

Tags: bash, rhel, fstab, uuid

I placed an entry in my fstab file to add a swap partition.

I used output of a bash command to get the UUID of vdb1 partition(I can't copy paste).

Like this:

```
UUID=$(blkid -o value -s UUID /dev/vdb1)  swap   swap  defaults 0 0
```

I'm getting a parse error when I run 'mount -a'.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: `fstab` is not a shell script. Why don't you just use `/dev/vdb1` as the first field (or add the actual UUID of the device directly)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Kusalananda comments, fstab cannot interpret embedded shell commands, resulting in your fstab causing this error.

With regards to your comment about cut/paste - I understand that typing in a uuid is daunting and likely error prone, but you could simply append the uuid to the end of your fstab by executing:

```
blkid -o value -s UUID >> /etc/fstab
```

... And then editing /etc/fstab in order to edit the 'junk' uuid line into a valid syntax.

I suggest this only as a way of compensating for the lack of a mouse/copy/paste facility.

If you don't fully understand what I am proposing here then do not do this! It will make your fstab syntax invalid, and prevent your system from booting until corrected.

Comment: never thought of appending, thanks.

Comment: You could avoid the invalid syntax step with something more complex such as `printf 'UUID=%s\tswap\tswap\tdefaults\t0\t0\n' "$(blkid -o value -s UUID /dev/vdb1)"`  (test it out before adding `>>/etc/fstab` to append it to the file).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer seems so ominous!

While modifying fstab can be dangerous, especially for someone new to linux systems, at least mitigate some stress and that danger by first making a copy (as should be your habit on such operations).

E.g.
`cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.copy` or `cp /etc/fstab ~/fstab.copy`

and for the blkid command to output the UUID:
`blkid -o value -s UUID >> /etc/fstab.copy`

perform your editing on `fstab.copy` to [ensure](https://serverfault.com/questions/174181/how-do-you-validate-fstab-without-rebooting) your syntax looks good. When your `fstab.copy` file is perfect to the best of your understanding, save `fstab.copy` as /etc/fstab. be sure not to have anything unexpected in there, like a cr/lf pair for example.

see link "ensure" above for next step (test w/ mount). For a more [detailed explanation](https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2019/01/21/how-to-verify-fstab-file/) about the mount test vs reboot.

Verify your new fstab:
`mount -fav`

Depending on the system feedback, you'll know whether it's safe to reboot, etc. No harm. no foul.
:)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/451408)

Comment: that makes sense, @TobySpeight